# Push multiple packages to private nuget (VSTS) with one command

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to push multiple nuget packages at ONCE to private VSTS nuget server.

I searched doco but could not find a batch Push command. I'm using the command below which seems to overwrite already existing nuget packages on VSTS.

```
nuget push mynuget.nupkg -Source https://myvsts.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/SitecorePackages/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey VSTS
```

UPDATE:

I used the push *.nupkg however, I can see only the 8.1.x version pushed.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to overwrite existing packages on VSTS. nuget.exe allows wildcards for push, so you could say `nuget push *.nupkg -Source https://myvsts.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/SitecorePackages/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey VSTS`.

Comment: Thanks @MattCooper but when I tried with *.nupkg, it shows error message "Failed to process request: 'conflict'. The remote server returned 409 Confilct..."

Comment: That's because it's not possible to overwrite the same package id + version. See this topic on [immutability](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/feeds/immutability).

Comment: Ok, I deleted and published 2 packages with *.nupkg. However, I can see only the last one. Somehow the last seems to override the first. See the screenshot attached on original post

Comment: Recently, nuget push got the `-SkipDuplicate` argument to allow this to work.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a powershell script you can use to bulk push NuGet packages to a VSTS feed. It will ignore any of the .symbols.nuget files:

```
set-location \\path\to\nugetpackages

$files=get-childitem | where {$_.Name -like "*.nupkg" -and $_.Name -notlike "*symbols*"}

foreach($file in $files) {
  .\NuGet.exe push -Source "MySource" -ApiKey key $file.name
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, I exclude previously uploaded packages from the "*packages*" folder and it contains only packages that not exists in local server. After that I use below command and it works fine.

```
nuget.exe push -Source "MyFeedName" -ApiKey VSTS packages\**\*.nupkg
```

Comment: I just used the same technique to bulk push everything from our old server to the new one - the `**` wildcard performs a recursive folder search and is really simple and useful for this.

Comment: The backslashes are important. I mostly use forward slashes since it works on all platforms, but on windows this fails: packages/**/*.nupkg

Comment: You can also use the '-SkipDuplicate' option of Azure CLI to skip already uploaded packages.