# TFS Build Configuration - Nuget Publisher

Tags: tfs, build, devops

We are using TFS and nexus package manager. For the CI we have Nuget Publisher task.

For the Path/Pattern to nupkg I wrote: `"^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg;-:**/packages/^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg;-:^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg"`

I want to say *take nupkg files which do not contain SNAPSHOT in the file name*.

- 1-C:_work\2\s\test-project.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-umut.nupkg
- 2-C:_work\2\s\test-project.1.0.1.nupkg

I want to take the second file.

But when I start the build, I get the error:

```
Starting: NuGet Publisher 
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet Publisher
Description  : Deprecated: use the “NuGet” task instead. It works with the new Tool Installer framework so you can easily use new versions of NuGet without waiting for a task update, provides better support for authenticated feeds outside this account/collection, and uses NuGet 4 by default.
Version      : 0.2.37
Author       : Lawrence Gripper
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627417)
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Error: No matching files were found with search pattern: C:\_work\2\s\**\*^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg;-:**\packages\**\*^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg;-:**\*^((?!SNAPSHOT).)*nupkg
Packages failed to publish
******************************************************************************
Finishing: NuGet Publisher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path/Pattern to nupkg` argument doesn't support `!` wildcard, it supports:

[image]

You need to use powershell script to filter and publish the packages.

@TetraDev in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185121/push-multiple-packages-to-private-nuget-vsts-with-one-command) provides a powershell script to bulk push NuGet packages to a VSTS feed. It will ignore any of the .symbols.nuget files:

```
set-location \\path\to\nugetpackages

$files=get-childitem | where {$_.Name -like "*.nupkg" -and $_.Name -notlike "*symbols*"}

foreach($file in $files) {
  .\NuGet.exe push -Source "MySource" -ApiKey key $file.name
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I think image url is false. Can you check this ?

Comment: Sorry, which url?

Comment: you wrote that "it support  https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0jVz.png"  but picture url is invalid .

Comment: You can check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/package/prev-versions/nuget-publisher-0?view=vsts#arguments.

Comment: "set-location C:\_work\2\b\
$files=get-childitem | where {$_.Name -like "*.nupkg" -and $_.Name -notlike "*symbols*"}"     for this code , its run and found my package which is I want. 

But  ".\NuGet.exe push -Source "MySource" -ApiKey key $file.name" for this code I get a error . 
2018-07-25T08:43:47.7000752Z ##[error]C:\_work\2\b\nuget.exe : The term 'C:\_work\2\b\nuget.exe' is not recognized as the n
ame of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,